# I cannot save a specific datetime value in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

when i try to update an item i get this error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2023-03-26 02:36:24' for column 'posted_at' at row 1 (SQL: update `table_name` set `posted_at` = 2023-03-26 02:36:24, `table_name`.`updated_at` = 2023-11-16 10:14:52 where `id` = 934579)

Column type is timestamp and it's casted as datetime, never had this issue before, only this value is crashing.

I tried nothing because its a normal datetime string.

Comment: when do the clocks move forward where you are?

Comment: in 2023 it was actually 26 march ...

Comment: issue with format of the datetime value you are trying to insert into 'posted_at' column

Comment: @HasanRaza i have tried '2023-03-27 02:36:24' ,  '2023-03-25 02:36:24' and '2023-03-26 15:36:24', they all work, also i'm not entering this manually, this is an update which gets the value from an api.

Comment: Enclose datetime value in single quotes in your update query

Comment: update table_name set posted_at = '2023-03-26 02:36:24', table_name.updated_at = '2023-11-16 10:14:52' where id = 934579

Answer (score 2):

If the error occurs due to a datetime value like `2023-03-26 02:36:24` falling in the Daylight Saving Time (DST) transition hour, it's likely because this specific time doesn't exist in local time.

During DST changes, typically in March, clocks are moved forward by an hour, skipping times like `02:00` to `02:59`.

Solution:

Adjust these datetime values to fall outside the DST transition hour. For example, you can add an hour to these times to make them valid. In your application, implement a check for DST transition periods and automatically adjust any datetime values that fall within this skipped hour.

This approach ensures that your timestamps remain consistent and valid, even during DST changes.

Comment: How would you do that in a Laravel application to handle all cases? I don't think adding if statements on every instance is the best way to handle it!

Comment: @altiinberiisha If your PHP application handles time zones correctly, you should be able to validate or fix dates beforehand: https://3v4l.org/QivQX (see that no error is reported, but date is automatically fixed). I don't know how Laravel handles dates.

Comment: This looks so like an AI generated answer that a follow up question isn't likely to be answered. You might wish to raise a specific question about laravel/php dst management.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  this is the value that i received from a specific api '2023-03-26T02:27:20+0000', and my php aplication has UTC timezone, which means 
    $date = new \DateTime('2023-03-26T02:27:20+0000', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
outputs the same datetime.

Comment: If MySQL is not using UTC, you need to convert that date to your local time zone. Otherwise, you're storing as local date what's actually a UTC date.